# Map with higher-order functions

Tags: scala

What are the differences between these statements?

```
val numbers = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
numbers map println
// vs.
numbers map (x => println(x))
```

And how does Scala know *println* will repeatedly take care of each number of *numbers*?

Thank you.

Comment: What you are doing in the second example is unnecessary function wrapping - you have a function (`println`) which already does what you want, and then you wrap it in an anonymous function (a lambda expression) which does nothing more than pass on the argument to `println`.

Comment: `println` is not a function, it's a method. You can't pass a method around, methods aren't objects in Scala. So, you have to wrap it in a function *anyway*. You can do this via η-expansion using the `_` underscore (`println _`), or, if Scala can infer from the context that you don't want to call the method but instead convert it to a function (as is the case here), then it will perform *implicit* η-expansion for you. Either way, whether you use explicit η-expansion, implicit η-expansion or an explicit λ, you have to create a function from the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What are the differences between these statements?
>
> ```
> val numbers = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
> numbers map println
> // vs.
> numbers map (x => println(x))
> ```

`map` takes as its argument a function which transforms a single element. `map` will then apply this function to every element and return a collection with the transformed elements. (Which, BTW, is why this code makes no sense: a) the return value of `map` is ignored, and b) `println` always returns `Unit`, so you will end up with a list of `Unit`s. `foreach` would be the correct method to use here.)

In your second example, you pass a λ (an anonymous first-class function object) to `map`.

In the first example, what *exactly* do you pass to `map`? It looks like you are passing a method, but that cannot be: a) `map` takes a function, not a method, and b) methods aren't objects, so you simply *can't* pass them around anyway. You have to somehow convert and/or wrap the method to/in a function.

In your second example, you are doing that very explicitly: you have a function which calls the method. The first example is more implicit. Scala has a feature called η-expansion, that lets you "lift" a method to function, which will partially apply the method to its implicit `this` argument, but leave its other (regular) parameters unbound.

The syntax for this is the ubiquitous underscore: `foo.bar _` means "take the method `bar` of `foo`, bind its `this` to `foo` and convert it into a function". In this particular case, you take `println`, bind its `this` to the top-level REPL context object (which doesn't really matter, since `println` doesn't actually care about its `this`, it is used like a procedure) and turn it into a function.

But wait, there's no underscore? That's right. In cases where the Scala compiler can determine that you don't actually want to *call* the method but wrap it into a function (i.e. when you don't pass an argument list, the method expects an argument list, and the context expects a type that is compatible with the type of the method), then Scala will perform *implicit η-expansion* for you.

So, let's get back to your question:

> What are the differences between these statements?

Well, on the one hand, the differences are what I described above: the first example uses implicit η-expansion, the second example uses an explicit λ. OTOH, there are no differences: both of them create a function from the `println` method, the second one just does it in a more convoluted way.

> And how does Scala know *println* will repeatedly take care of each number of *numbers*?

It doesn't. a) it's not `println` that "takes care of each number", it's `map` that does it, and b) Scala doesn't know anything, that's just how `map` was written.

Very simplistic, `map` looks like this:

```
sealed trait MyList[+T] {
  def map[U](function: T ⇒ U): MyList[U]
  def foreach(procedure: T ⇒ Unit)
}

case object EmptyList extends MyList[Nothing] {
  // mapping the empty list returns the empty list
  def map[U](function: Nothing ⇒ U) = EmptyList

  def foreach(procedure: Nothing ⇒ Unit) = ()
}

final case class ListCell[+T](first: T, rest: MyList[T]) extends MyList[T] {
  // mapping a non-empty list returns the result of transforming the first 
  // element of the list and recursively mapping the rest of the list
  def map[U](function: T ⇒ U) = ListCell(function(first), rest map function)

  def foreach(procedure: T ⇒ Unit) = { procedure(first); rest foreach procedure }
}
```

And here's how we use our simple little list:

```
val list: MyList[Short] = ListCell(1, ListCell(2, ListCell(3, EmptyList)))

list map (1+)
// => ListCell(2, ListCell(3, ListCell(4, EmptyList)))

list map(_.toString)
// => ListCell(1, ListCell(2, ListCell(3, EmptyList)))

list map println
// 1
// 2
// 3
// => ListCell((), ListCell((), ListCell((), EmptyList)))
// here you can see the useless list of Units that is returned

list foreach println
// 1
// 2
// 3
// foreach just returns nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

`map` is expecting a function that that a value and produces a value. In your first example, you provide such a function explicitly by giving a lambda. In the second case, the compiler can inspect the types and see that `println : A => Unit`. Note that normally, you would not want to use `map` for a function that produces `Unit`, that's more appropriate to `foreach`.

Answer (score 2):

The two statements have the same semantic, the second version just add a level of indirection that is not actually required for things to work.

The thing is that the map function takes as an argument a function able to operate on an Int and producing a Unit:

```
final def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): List[B]
```

In your example A is Int and B is Unit.

Now if you take a look at the signature of the println method and the one of your anonymous function, you'll notice that they are actually the same:

```
def println(x: Any): Unit
(x => println(x)): Any -> Unit
```

What is happening is that the map function iterates through the element in the list and for each element x it calls the function f(x). Since both println and the anonymous function accept Any as an input map can safely pass them the x Int.

Using the anonymous function you are just adding an intermediate function call step.